# How do I get material tabs in the safe area

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

I'm putting together a react-native app and want tabs along the top. I am using [createMaterialTopTabNavigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/material-top-tab-navigator.html) for the tabs and this works fine. However when I run the app on the newest iPhone simulator, the tabs bleed into the sensor bar. In trying to solve this, people suggest using the [safeareaview](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/safeareaview) but it doesn't seem to be any information on how to combine this with an outer tabs parent.

Any help that you guys could offer I would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import React from 'react';
import { createMaterialTopTabNavigator, SafeAreaView, MaterialTopTabBar } from 'react-navigation';

const SafeAreaMaterialTopTabBar = ({ ...props }) => (
  <SafeAreaView>
    <MaterialTopTabBar {...props} />
  </SafeAreaView>
);

const options = {
  tabBarComponent: props => (<SafeAreaMaterialTopTabBar {...props} />),
};

const RentalsTopTabNavigator = createMaterialTopTabNavigator({
  [Routes.ROUTE_1]: {
    screen: Screen1,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'Tab1',
    },
  },
  [Routes.ROUTE_2]: {
    screen: Screen2,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'Tab 2',
    },
  },
}, options);
```

Comment: It should be noted that `createMaterialTopTabNavigator` and `MaterialTopTabBar` now should be imported from the module `react-navigation-tabs`